# CRUD methods and endpoints for RESTful api not being generated in proxy api server

Tags: javascript, rest, api, loopbackjs

I'm trying to proxy a server (http://www.swapi.co/api/starships for practice, then a Salesforce api for production). This will be the mobile backend for a React Native app. I'm following the documentation here: http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/REST-connector.html#resource-operations. However, when using the generators to create a 'starship' datasource that uses CRUD operations and a Starship model, nothing shows up when I try to explore the api using the built-in explorer. When proxying a RESTful API, I'd like to expose it using a RESTful API, is this even available yet with Loopback?

Here is the screenshot of the explorer I'm using to view the api:

[image: Loopback api explorer screenshot]

Here are the steps I'm taking:

```
$ slc loopback:datasource
? Enter the data-source name: starship
? Select the connector for starship: REST Services (supported by StrongLoop)
? Base URL for the REST service: http://www.swapi.co/api/starship
? Default options for the request: [left blank, hit enter]
? An array of operation templates: [left blank, hit enter]
? Use default CRUD mapping: (y/N) Y

$ slc loopback:model
? Enter model name: Starship
? Select data-source to attach Starship to: starship (rest)
? Select model's base class: Model
? Expose Person via the REST API? (Y/n) Y
? Custom plural form (used to build REST URL): starships
? Common model or server only? common

Let's add some Starship properties now.

Enter an empty property name when done.
? Property name: [left empty, hit enter]

$ npm start

> wfsapi@1.0.0 start /Users/me/projects/wfsapi
> node .

Web server listening at: http://0.0.0.0:3000
Browse your REST API at http://0.0.0.0:3000/explorer
```

However, when I navigate to the explorer, only the Users api shows up, nothing for Starships. Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong? Here are the contents of the generated files that I could find:

common/models/starship.js

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (Starship) {

};
```

common/models/starship.json

```
{
    "name": "Starship",
    "plural": "starships",
    "base": "Model",
    "idInjection": true,
    "options": {
        "validateUpsert": true
    },
    "properties":  {},
    "validations":  [],
    "relations": {},
    "acls": [],
    "methods": {}
}
```

server/datasources.json

```
{
  "db": {
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "memory"
  },
  "starship": {
    "name": "starship",
    "baseURL": "http://www.swapi.co/api/starships",
    "crud": true,
    "connector": "rest"
  }
}
```

server/model-config.json

```
{ 
  ... 
  "Starship": {
    "datasource": "starship",
    "public": true
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the url are you trying to open to explore your api? Can you post a picture or detail what error is shown?

Comment: I just added a screenshot of the Loopback explorer api that I navigate to after running the api server. There are no errors in the server console where the server is running, it's just not generating the CRUD methods for the model. I'm not sure how the generators are supposed to be used to generate CRUD models connected to a 3rd party api using the loopback-rest-connector. I must be doing something wrong, but I just don't see it. Are you asking about errors in the server terminal or errors in the browser console?

Comment: I just checked, there are no errors in the browser console either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you're using Model as base instead of PersistedModel.

Model doesn't have remote methods to access.

You need change your common/models/starship.json to

```
{
     "name": "Starship",
     "plural": "starships",
     "base": "PersistedModel",
     "idInjection": true,
     "options": {
         "validateUpsert": true
     },
     "properties":  {},
     "validations":  [],
     "relations": {},
     "acls": [],
     "methods": {}
}
```

Check http://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#persistedmodel for more information.

Comment: This was spot on! I didn't think to check the documentation for Model and PersistedModel. But if I had thought about it, the api that I'm proxying to, is database backed, hence the RESTful CRUD api.